# mod_rewrite: My links no longer work after redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My .htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /subdirectory/$1 [L,R=301]

# capture user name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?user=$1

ErrorDocument 404 /subdirectory/index.php
```

My intention was:

- to make nice URLs like http://domain.com/subdirectory/james/ => http://domain.com/subdirectory/index.php?user=james
- ignore trailing slashes so that /james and /james/ would work
- redirect all access to non existent folders/files to /subdirectory/index.php

All that works fine, but my problem is when someone enters URLs like...

```
http://domain.com/subdirectory/james/yyy
http://domain.com/subdirectory/james/yyy/zzz
http://domain.com/subdirectory/james/yyy/zzz/nonexistent.html
```

... and they get redirected to my /subdirectory/index.php, all the links in index.php like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="something.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/something.js"></script>
<img src="images/picture.jpg">
```

... get maligned to something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/james/yyy/zzz/something.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/james/yyy/zzz/lib/something.js"></script>
<img src="/james/yyy/zzz/images/picture.jpg">
```

What could I be doing wrong? Is my handling of trailing slashes correct? Is my usage of ErrorDocument the proper way to do it?

This my first attempt at working with .htaccess and mod_rewrite. And this is also my first Stackoverflow question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a 404.php file that contains:

```
<? header('location: /subdirectory'); ?> // redirect to a valid subdirectory/file
```

and changing my ErrorDocument entry to:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /subdirectory/404.php
```

Apparently, the problem was with using relative links. The above solution allowed me to preserve my original relative links.

I hope this helps someone too.